# Python 3 converting datafile to dictionary with multiple values per key and displaying it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have looked all over for an answer but could not find one. I have a datafile with these key/values:

```
oolong:8580.0:7201.25:8900.0 
earl grey:10225.25:9025.0:9505.0
green:6700.1:5012.45:6011.0
mint:9285.15:8276.1:8705.0
jasmine:7901.25:4267.0:7056.5
```

The data reads as follows – tea_name:store1_Sales:store2_Sales:store3_Sales

And I need to be able to display this output:

```
>>> earl grey 10225.25 9025.00 9505.00 28755.25
green 6700.10 5012.45 6011.00 17723.55
jasmine 7901.25 4267.00 7056.50 19224.75
mint 9285.15 8276.10 8705.00 26266.25
oolong 8580.00 7201.25 8900.00 24681.25
       42691.75 33781.80 40177.50
```

I understand that I can load the file as a list using

```
with open('tea.txt') as f:
   teas = f.read().splitlines()
```

I don't know how to convert a list into a dict with multiple values for single keys. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I understand how to get the list and convert into a dictionary now. Thanks guys!

Comment: A key in a dictionary can have a single object behind it - but that object can be a list, or another dictionary. Have a think about how you would convert a line like `oolong:8580.0:7201.25:8900.0` into `teas['oolong'] = [8580.0, 7201.25, 8900.0]` using methods like `.split()`

Comment: Can teas repeat in your data file or have multiple data lines? If so, you may want a list of dicts container instead of dictionary container.

Comment: @Parfait Teas can not repeat in my data file! Sorry for the slow response.

Comment: If you now have your answer, you should select from one of the answers below and mark it as the "solution".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to approach this problem. I will show you one way to read the tea leaves.

```
teas = {}
with open('tea.txt') as f:
    # step through the file, line by line,
    # so that you don't read in a huge file all at once
    for line in f:
        # split the line by your delimiter ':'
        t = line.split(':')
        # create your dictionary with a key, value pair
        teas[t[0]] = t[1:]
```

If you need the numerical values of each list, you can map them to the appropriate data type. Here are two example of how to change the final line above to get numerical lists / arrays.

- You can do this with simple built in functions:

  ```
  teas[t[0]] = map(float, t[1:])
  ```
- Or, you can use a `numpy` array

  ```
  import numpy
  # ....
  teas[t[0]] = numpy.array(t[1:], dtype=float)
  ```

The final dictionary looks like this:

```
{'earl grey': (10225.25, 9025.0, 9505.0),
 'green': (6700.1, 5012.45, 6011.0),
 'jasmine': (7901.25, 4267.0, 7056.5),
 'mint': (9285.15, 8276.1, 8705.0),
 'oolong': (8580.0, 7201.25, 8900.0)}
```

Answer (score 2):

the simplest way to get the dict:

```
with open('1.txt') as f:    
    data = {}
    for row in f:                   
        row = row.strip().split(':')
        data[row[0]] = row[1:]

for key, value in data.items():     
    print('%s %s %s' % (key, ' '.join(value), sum([float(v) for v in value])))
```

Comment: While this is a good way to get the data into `dict` form, it doesn't fully answer the original question, which asked for cumulative sums as the last element in each value of the dict.

Comment: with open('tea.txt') as f: 
 data = {}
    for row in f:          
     row = row.strip().split(':')
     data[row[0]] = row[1:]

for key, value in data.items():  
 print('%s %s %s' % (key, ' '.join(value), sum([float(v) for v in value])))

Comment: 'with open('1.txt') as f: 
 data = {}
    for row in f:          
     row = row.strip().split(':')
     data[row[0]] = row[1:]

for key, value in data.items():  
 print('%s %s %s' % (key, ' '.join(value), sum([float(v) for v in value])))'

Comment: sorry for comments

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` for this, easily:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# makes it easy to read globs of text like the data you posted above
data = StringIO('''oolong:8580.0:7201.25:8900.0 
earl grey:10225.25:9025.0:9505.0
green:6700.1:5012.45:6011.0
mint:9285.15:8276.1:8705.0
jasmine:7901.25:4267.0:7056.5''')

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep = ':', header = None)

# returns a list of column names from the string you have above
df.columns = "tea_name:store1_Sales:store2_Sales:store3_Sales".split(':')

# add up the sales for stores 1, 2, and 3 for each type of tea to get total sales for a given tea
df['total_sales'] = df[['store1_Sales', 'store2_Sales', 'store3_Sales']].sum(axis = 1)
```

Here's the result:

```
>>> df
    tea_name  store1_Sales  store2_Sales  store3_Sales  total_sales
0     oolong       8580.00       7201.25        8900.0     24681.25
1  earl grey      10225.25       9025.00        9505.0     28755.25
2      green       6700.10       5012.45        6011.0     17723.55
3       mint       9285.15       8276.10        8705.0     26266.25
4    jasmine       7901.25       4267.00        7056.5     19224.75
```

Edit: to get a `dict` from this `pandas.DataFrame` object, simply do:

```
>>> df.to_dict()
{'store1_Sales': {0: 8580.0, 1: 10225.25, 2: 6700.1000000000004, 3: 9285.1499999999996, 4: 7901.25}, 'tea_name': {0: 'oolong', 1: 'earl grey', 2: 'green', 3: 'mint', 4: 'jasmine'}, 'total_sales': {0: 24681.25, 1: 28755.25, 2: 17723.549999999999, 3: 26266.25, 4: 19224.75}, 'store3_Sales': {0: 8900.0, 1: 9505.0, 2: 6011.0, 3: 8705.0, 4: 7056.5}, 'store2_Sales': {0: 7201.25, 1: 9025.0, 2: 5012.4499999999998, 3: 8276.1000000000004, 4: 4267.0}}
```

Edit2: ignoring `pandas`, you can accomplish what you want in base Python like this,

```
teas_dict = {}
for row in teas:
    row_list = row.split(':')
    tea = row_list[0] # tea name is always the first element in a row
    sales = row_list[1:] # remaining elements in row_list are sales data
    teas_dict[tea] = sales
```

Equivalently, using a `dict` comprehension:

```
>>> teas_dict = {row.split(':')[0]: row.split(':')[1:] for row in teas}
>>> teas_dict
{'earl grey': ['10225.25', '9025.0', '9505.0'], 'green': ['6700.1', '5012.45', '6011.0'], 'oolong': ['8580.0', '7201.25', '8900.0 '], 'mint': ['9285.15', '8276.1', '8705.0'], 'jasmine': ['7901.25', '4267.0', '7056.5']}
```

Finally, to get your cumulative sales sum at the end:

```
for tea in teas_dict:
    total_sales = sum(map(float, teas_dict[tea]))
    teas_dict[tea].append(total_sales)
```

Result:

```
>>> teas_dict
{'earl grey': ['10225.25', '9025.0', '9505.0', 28755.25], 'green': ['6700.1', '5012.45', '6011.0', 17723.55], 'oolong': ['8580.0', '7201.25', '8900.0 ', 24681.25], 'mint': ['9285.15', '8276.1', '8705.0', 26266.25], 'jasmine': ['7901.25', '4267.0', '7056.5', 19224.75]}
```